# Add Emoticons in BlackBerry 10 App?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I need to insert the emoticons/smileys in my app. is it possible in bb 10 ?  Any built in code for that or need to customize that images in the app?
i have enabled the emoticons in textfield and labelfield using the following code.it works but i need to select the emoticons using emoticons popup dialog

```
content {
      flags: TextContentFlag.Emoticons
   }
```

I have attached the image for ref.

Thanks,[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think presently Emoticon is presently not there i think so,Plz refer roadMaps
https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/roadmap/